# Is it possible to modify or "customize" operators in an existing class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operators, overriding

I have a vector of pairs of ints, *i.e.*

```
std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > V;
```

I wanted to sort this vector, so I wrote a quicksort implementation. Thankfully, [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) already defines intelligent comparison operators such that

```
[[3, 1], [1, 7], [3, 5]]
```

sorts to

```
[[1, 7], [3, 1], [3, 5]]
```

*i.e.* sorting by the first element of each pair, using the second element as a tiebreaker.

But what I actually want is to compare the second element in *decreasing* order. So the above example should be sorted as

```
[[1, 7], [3, 5], [3, 1]]
```

Is it possible to override the comparison operators of `std::pair` so that I can sort by increasing first- and decreasing second-element? If not, what's the best way to achieve this, design-wise?

I thought about deriving a child class from `std::pair` that overrode all the comparison operators, but this required `reinterpret_cast`ing `std::pair<int, int>*` to pointers to my child class, which feels very wrong.

Is a separate, static helper class the only way then? (Aside from hacks like multiplying all the second elements by -1, given knowledge that all values are positive.)

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the general design principle of the C++ library, and use comparators. Ordered associative container templates, like `std::set`, have an optional template parameter, a comparator class that sets the sorting order. For example:

```
std::set<int>
```

Gives you a set that orders its `int` values in the natural, increasing, order. Iterating over this stock set will iterate over its values from smallest to highest values.

But that's only because `std::set` really has a second template parameter, the comparator, which defaults to [std::less](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) which is, basically, a wrapper for the `<` operator. This `std::set` is really:

```
std::set<int, std::less<int>>
```

(There's also a third template parameter, which is not relevant for the purpose of this discussion).

If you wanted to you could declare, instead, a:

```
std::set<int, std::greater<int>>
```

And then, if you were to iterate over this set, you would discover that you'll be iterating from the largest to the smallest values in the set. In all other respects this set works just like an ordinary set.

Similarly, let's talk about that quicksort implementation you wrote. Your quicksort uses the `<` operator directly to compare your `std::pair`s. You should simply rewrite your quicksort implementation to take an additional parameter, a comparator, that specifies the sorting order. Instead of just using the overloaded `<` operator, your quicksort implementation would invoke the comparator instead, to compare the two pairs.

Now, you'll be able to quicksort your pairs in any order you can specify with a single callable object that takes two arbitrary `std::pair`s, and computes their relative order.

Comment: I see, so you're saying the custom comparison should exist outside of any relation to `std::pair`, instead implemented as part of the quicksort implementation. Sounds clean, I'll do it that way. Still, I'm curious about something, more from a theory perspective:

Comment: If, say, a bunch of algorithms in `<algorithm>` or some other library, are manipulating and sorting my vector of `std::pair`s just fine. But say, now, I want all of them to consider a different ordering (_e.g._ descending second element). Then doesn't it seem wasteful to ask every algorithm to take a comparator parameter? Do you have any insight as to why the "ordering" of a type shouldn't be intrinsic to the type, as opposed to a responsibility of the things manipulating that type?